# QGIS 2.18 SAGA Change Data Storage

Tags: saga, qgis-2.18, bit-depth

I tried to use Change Data Storage to change the bit depth of some rasters, but it doesn't work or gives me vague errors

I first tried to batch convert some rasters to unsigned 1 byte interger, I selected [1]unsigned 1 byte interger, 0 offset, scale of 1, load in QGIS? no, and obviously filled in the file names. It created some temp files for the calculations, but did not finish. It said "The following layers were not correctly generated. Converted Grid You can check the log messages to find more information about the execution of the algorithm"

I also tried to singly convert some rasters using the same tool and parameters. It created blank (no data) rasters, but did not give an error message

Anybody know the source of these errors?

Comment: Your QGIS 2.18.x is the latest version?

Comment: It's 2.18.18. Unless I'm mistaken that's the last one they made before moving on to 3

Comment: I am mistaken. Looks like there's a 2.18.19 now

Comment: I'm downloading the newer version, but I suspect the problem is from user error and not a glitch in the program, so I'm not sure how much good that'll do...

Comment: Not sure which one work better in your environment, but could you try `change data storage` and `convert data storage type`?

Comment: ....user error?

Comment: So I with /.19, and I got

 "The following layers were not correctly generated.
Converted Grid
You can check the log messages to find more information about the execution of the algorithm"

I also tried convert data storage type (which actually seemed more appropriate to what I was doing), and it failed and told me

"'NoneType' object has no attribute 'crs' See log for more details"

Comment: User error meaning not checking a box I needed to check or a wrong setting or something like that. I'm pretty new to QGIS